# Why can't flying races fly while wearing armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, races, armor, flight

No flying race has the ability to fly while wearing any armor other than light armor. Is there a balance issue that this causes?

If there is, then what is the difference between a flying race in plate armor and a monk or barbarian flying race? The latter can have an even higher armor class, so what is the issue?

Comment: I doubt there can be a good objective answer unless one of the game designers commented on the matter.

Comment: correction: flying races (just going off Aarakocra here) can indeed wear any kind of armor. They just can't fly with it unless it's light.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That... is really inappropriate. Grievances or disagreements with how the moderation team handles things belongs on Meta, not here, and does not justify breaking the rules. _That said_, I’m voting to reopen this question because it’s not designer-intent at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Because heavy armor is heavy and impairs movement.

The descriptions of [medium armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#MediumArmor) and [heavy armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#HeavyArmor) given in the *Player's Handbook*/Basic Rules answer this question for us:

> ##### Medium Armor
>
> Medium armor offers more protection than light armor, but it also impairs movement more. [...]

> ##### Heavy Armor
>
> Of all the armor categories, heavy armor offers the best protection. These suits of armor cover the entire body and are designed to stop a wide range of attacks. Only proficient warriors can manage their weight and bulk.

While the lightest medium armor only weighs 12 pounds, the others range from 20 to 40 pounds. The lightest heavy armor is 40 pounds, and the heaviest is 65 pounds. Flying races, such as the Aarakocra, cannot fly while wearing these armors because the level of protection the provide comes at the cost of mobility. The armor is too heavy or bulky to allow for the nimbleness required for flight.

#### Balance? Probably not a problem.

As outlined above, the restriction is very plainly situated within the realm of narrative. The armor doesn't allow a flying creature to move the way they need to for flying. However, this shouldn't be an issue of balance. There are numerous ways to obtain a flying speed between spells and magic items, and if those don't break your campaign, neither will letting an Aarakocra cruise around wearing chain mail. In my experience, most of the parties I've played with or been the DM for have obtained a means of flight by early to mid Tier 2 (levels 5-7 or so), and the "always on" flight of a flying race becomes much less interesting and powerful.

Answer (score 2):

## From a RP perspective: because it's cumbersome

As the names imply, light armor is generally lighter than medium or heavy armor. And that's not all: it's also more unwieldy and gets more in the way. Basic light armor might be fabric-based and at least somewhat soft and flexible, whereas full plate armor (while being more flexible than most people think) is much more unwieldy and tiring to wear, much less fly in.

tl;dr: heavier armor than light is more cumbersome and restricts movement more, getting in the way of flight.

## From a design perspective: balancing

Having innate fly speed from your race is already a powerful trait. Being limited to wearing light armor is just a way of mitigating that benefit, as flying 30 feet above an enemy that lacks ranged combat capabilities is already infinitely better than standing next to it, regardless of your armor class (even at 100 AC, a crit would still hit you). And even enemies with ranged attacks usually have more powerful melee than ranged attacks (source: experience).

Thus, since you can only be targeted by ranged attacks unless you're on the ground (by choice or by virtue of location), limiting armor effectiveness provides balancing.

---

That being said, you're right that classes with other AC calculations such as barbarians or monks can ignore this restriction. However, these are edge cases, and when designing a system like 5e, there needs to be a balance (no pun intended) between balancing and logical sense. "Your base armor class can't be higher than X" makes no sense, but "Heavier armor is too unwieldy to fly with, thus implicitly limiting you to 12 + DEX AC in most cases" is.

Of course, with 20 STR, you can normally carry 300 pounds, which makes even the 65 pounds of plate armor seem little. But I would wager that most Aarakocra players don't play STR-focused characters (especially when ignoring barbarians), and for an 8-STR-character, plate armor is half the total carrying capacity. Besides, it's unclear whether a high STR score would translate to flight muscles as well, or if those are magic-fueled anyway (according to real world physics, they would have to be, unless you imagine Aarakocra with a gigantic wing span of several meters - but given that the same problem would be true for dragons, it probably should be ignored).

Either way, if you do happen to play a high-STR-non-barbarian-Aarakocra, feel free to discuss with your DM if the armor requirement can be lifted (or changed to some variation of "you need x STR to wear medium and y STR to wear heavy amor")

Comment: About the RP perspective: there doesn't seem to be anything that stops _carrying_ a full plate while flying, which seems even more cumbersome than wearing one while flying.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir A swallow could likely carry a coconut attached to a strand of creeper, but could almost certainly not carry the coconut while wearing it as a suit of armor.

Comment: In terms of balance, I would say that it's *lighter* armor that tends to synergize better with flight. Who can actually make the most of attacking from above the range of return fire? The longest-range attacks are mostly either Dex-based weapons (thus favoring light armor), or spells (with most full caster classes not having heavy armor proficiency to begin with). So really the armor restriction is hitting the wrong targets.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov African or European?  And couldn't it just grip it by the husk?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Very true, but then there's [some experimental evidence](https://youtu.be/qzTwBQniLSc) that even a properly fitted full plate may be less restrictive than a coconut.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir Wow, the disadvantage on stealth make a lot of sense, doesn't it